# Return VBA Network Drive Letter for Different Users

Tags: vba, excel, network-programming

I've created a portal for myself and coworkers to download workbook templates that reference different network drives in an effort to consolidate.

The portal is hosted in the "Accounting" (Z:/) drive, but one of the workbooks references a spreadsheet in a different drive "BI" (Y:/).

This works splendidly on my machine, but my coworkers have different drive letters (e.g. M:/Accounting, U:/BI).

Is there a way to search a network for a name and return the drive letter?

Here's a rough approximation of my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub mySub()


dim WBaPath as String
dim WBbPath as String
WBaPath = "Y:\BI-Accounting\myWorkbook.xlsm"
WBbPath = "Z:\Portal\myOtherWorkbook.xlsm"
dim WBa as Workbook
dim WBb as Workbook
set WBa = Workbooks.open(WBaPath)
set WBb = ThisWorkbook

'Code to do stuff


End Sub
```

The folders and files will have the same name, but what is the best way to make sure that all users in my department can use these tools without having to reprogram and, preferably, without having to choose at run-time?

Comment: Use [UNC paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention) instead of drive letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [FileSystemObject's Drives property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243125(v=vs.60).aspx) to achieve this:

```
Function FindDriveLetter(shareToFind As String) As String
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim dc As Object
    Dim d As Object
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set dc = fs.Drives
    For Each d In dc
        If d.drivetype = 3 Then
            If UCase(d.sharename) = UCase(shareToFind) Then
                FindDriveLetter = d.driveletter
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
    FindDriveLetter = ""
End Function

Sub Test()
    MsgBox FindDriveLetter("\\SERVER01\SHAREXYZ\FILES")
    ' use whatever share name you have mapped to your "Y" or "Z" drive
    ' instead of "\\SERVER01\SHAREXYZ\FILES"
End Sub
```

---

But using a UNC path (e.g. `WBaPath = "\\SERVER01\SHAREXYZ\FILES\BI-Accounting\myWorkbook.xlsm"`) is usually easier.