# VBA - how to change drive (ChDrive) if letter mapping of the network drive is unknown

Tags: excel, vba, windows

For the project I am doing, I am going to open up a csv file based on user's choice. The csv file would sit in folder like `\\server\share\folder\file.csv` or `M:\folder\file.csv`.

```
dim PATH As String: PATH = "M:\folder\file.csv"
ChDrive (Left(PATH, 1))        ' point to the drive
ChDir PATH

' get csv file name
csv_file_name = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", , "Select a CSV file", , False)
```

*The code above opens up a select file box at PATH.*

The problem is, not all the machines have the same network drive mapping. For the same `\\server\share` combo, some people might map it to **M** and others might map it to **Z**. So instead, I was wondering if I can do something like `ChDrive "\\server\share\"`. Unfortunately, `ChDrive` only takes drive letter as paramter.

I was wondering if there's a more generic solution to a problem like this. Thanks!

Comment: I accepted Brax answer because I feel explicitly (i.e. UNC path) is favored. But if you are still looking for ways to find VBA network drive letter for different users, here is a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425183/return-vba-network-drive-letter-for-different-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function using the msoFileDialogOpen option and specify an initial filename:

```
Function FileOpen(initialFilename As String, Optional sDesc As String = "CSV Files (*.csv)", Optional sFilter As String = "*.csv") As String
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .initialFilename = initialFilename
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add sDesc, sFilter, 1
    .Title = "File Open"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then FileOpen = .SelectedItems(1)
  End With
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Sub Test()
  MsgBox FileOpen("\\server\share", "Select a File", "*.csv")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the timely response! I changed the `msoFileDialogOpen` to `msoFileDialogSelect` since I just need the file name for my case, but everything works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for adding that information. It adds value to this answer.